# python dictionary inside/outside for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to change one of my elements in the dictionary but if I were to put `new_alien` outside the loop, all the elements in the dictionary gets changed. Why is that?

```
#ALL aliens get changed when I put put the dictionary up here
new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}

aliens=[]

for alien_number in range(3):
    #if i put new_alien here only one alien dictionary gets changed in the for loop (correct code)
    #new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}
    aliens.append(new_alien)

print(aliens)

for alien in aliens[0:1]:
    if (alien['colour'] == 'green'):
        alien['colour'] = 'yellow'

print(aliens[0:2])
```

Output if `new_alien` is outside the loop:

```
[{'colour': 'green'}, {'colour': 'green'}, {'colour': 'green'}]
[{'colour': 'yellow'}, {'colour': 'yellow'}]
```

Output if `new_alien` is inside the loop:

```
[{'colour': 'green'}, {'colour': 'green'}, {'colour': 'green'}]
[{'colour': 'yellow'}, {'colour': 'green'}]
```

Notice how outside the loop ALL alien dictionary:colour gets changed to yellow.
Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because you keep appending the *same dictionary* to your list 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `new_alien` on the outside, you are appending the same object over and over again. You can print out the objects identity with [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#id) to see what I mean here:

**`new_alien` inside the loop:**

```
for alien_number in range(3): 
    new_alien = {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
    print(id(new_alien))
    aliens.append(new_alien)
```

Which outputs different object identities:

```
1577811864456
1577811864528
1577811864960
```

Therefore you are appending a different object every time. Different references to `new_alien`, 3 separate objects. If you change one object, only one object gets changed here. This is the correct way to do this.

**`new_alien` outside the loop:**

```
new_alien = {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}

for alien_number in range(3):
    print(id(new_alien))
    aliens.append(new_alien)
```

You get the same identities:

```
2763267730312
2763267730312
2763267730312
```

Which means you are appending the same object over and over again. This means that if you change one object, all of the objects will change. This is because they are all references to one object. Not the way to go if you want to modify them in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the problem now. Just to clarify, when I append the same object three times, it will still print those 3 objects (that are the same) 3 times. Another question is, why is it different inside the loop vs outside. I can see where I did wrong, just wondering why.

Comment: @SlowSloth, this is just one of those things in Python. If you declare an object **once** outside the loop, that is just **one** object. That's why when you print it, is prints the same object 3 times. Whereas if you create the object in the loop, you create a new object each iteration. Unless you don't want to ever modify `new_alien`, declaring it outside the loop is fine. Otherwise, your asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that since my output all looks the same. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, make sure to upvote any helpful answers and give an answer a green tick. if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[**Python Tutor**](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) is an online app that shows you what happens. You can paste your code in it and see how python interpreter runs the code.

Here is the explanation in plain text.

The following statement creates a new dict object, and the new_alien is just a reference of the dict object.

```
new_alien = {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
```

If you put the this statement outside the loop, all elements in the list refer to the same dict object (or the same memory space) as you don't create new one for each element.

Comment: Sorry, I am still having trouble understanding. After the first for loop, `aliens` has 3 aliens with colour green.

The loop after changes one of those aliens to yellow, why would it change the other two?

Comment: No, you don't have three aliens, you just have three references to the same alien.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you so much for the help and Python Tutor is extremely helpful!

Comment: The link appears to be dead - the endpoints return "forbidden"

Answer (score 1):

**case 1:** So, when you `append` `new_alien = {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}`into the list, it refers the same `object` of the memory. You can check memory reference by `id(Your_Object_Name)`. Basically it works like a global variable.

**case 2:** when you try to `append`  it from declaring inside of the loop it creates the different object with different memory reference.

Comment: Thank you I got it! :) appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you put it outside, you are appending the same `new_alien` object to the `aliens` dictionary. If you put it inside, you are creating 3 different `new_alien` objects and then appending it to `aliens`.

```
for loop (correct code)
    new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}<-create a new dictionary {"c": "g"} and put it 
                                     under the name new_alien
    aliens.append(new_alien) # add the new dictionary
```

Although they are all adding the same variable `new_alien`, what is binding to `new_alien` are different during each round of the loop. Everytime you have an assignment statement for `new_alien`, like `new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}`, you are (re)binding `new_alien` to a newly created dictionary. Thus, when later on you change one in `aliens`, it won't affect others.

---

While on the other case: `new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}` is **outside** the loop, the same object reference is inserted into the dictionary for 3 times. While you changed one of it to `"yellow"`, you do only change one. (There is in fact only one that you can change even though it looks there are 3 of it.) However, while you are printing it, you are also printing *the same dictionary stored* for 3 times! This is why it gives you the same result.

---

*Takeaways*:

- An object can have different names that all refer to it.
- A variable name can refer to different objects at different moments.

In the first case, `new_alien` refers to different dictionary object while the loop is executed at each step.

In the latter case, `new_alien` is outside the loop, we can see that `aliens[0]`, `aliens[1]`, and `aliens[2]` all refer to the same dictionary object. You change one of them, yes, only one object is changed. You change two of them; still, one same dictionary is changed. You read all of the three; you are just reading the same dictionary three times.

Answer (score 0):

An object in python is viewed as an address in memory under the hood. A variable name for an object is thus just a reference to the place in the computer's memory where that object is stored. If you run this line of code:

```
new_alien = {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
```

this creates an object in memory that can be referenced by the new_alien variable. If this line is outside of the loop it is run ONCE while if it is inside the loop it is run multiple times. When this line is run multiple times it means multiple objects are created in memory, but when it is run once only one object is created in memory and that is why they are all updated when it is declared on the outside; because they are all referencing the same memory location under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

That's called shallow copy , When you append that item you are actually appending same object and when you modify anything to it , it will affect the main object :

> Solution :

You [co/sho]uld use deepcopy :

```
from copy import deepcopy
#ALL aliens get changed when I put put the dictionary up here
new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}

aliens=[]

for alien_number in range(3):
    #if i put new_alien here only one alien dictionary gets changed in the for loop (correct code)
    #new_alien = {'colour': 'green'}
    aliens.append(deepcopy(new_alien))


for alien in aliens[0:1]:
    if (alien['colour'] == 'green'):
        alien['colour'] = 'yellow'

print(aliens[0:2])
print(new_alien)
```

output:

```
{'colour': 'green'}
[{'colour': 'yellow'}, {'colour': 'green'}]
{'colour': 'green'}
```